# Android find the address in the html body

Tags: android, html, webview

I have the RSS feed with title, author, description, and body. I display them in the Android web view. 
I need to find if the body has a mailing address. If it is there, I need to show them highlighted and clickable, which might launch a new page.
How can I do this?
A sample RSS feed:

```
<title><![CDATA[ NJ ‘computer geek’ latest to file beating claim against Harrah’s A.C. security ]]></title>
                    <author><![CDATA[ Sam Wood <br> PHILLY.COM ]]></author>
                    <description>
                                        </description>


                    <body><![CDATA[   <p><img style='float: left;height: 48px;padding: 0 8px 8px 0;width: 100px;' class='img_noborder partnerBadges' src='http://media.philly.com/designimages/partnerIcon-mobile-Phillycom.jpg' border='0'/></p>                                       <p>A New Jersey computer engineering student is the latest person to claim he was the victim of an unprovoked beating at the hands of security guards at an Atlantic City casino, bringing the total to at least four.</p>
<p>Richard Travellin, 23, filed suit in Bergen County court last week against Harrah&rsquo;s Atlantic City and its parent company, Caesars Entertainment Corp.</p>
<p>Travellin, who his attorney described as a &ldquo;shy computer geek,&rdquo; joins a mother and daughter from Florida and two Atlantic County cab drivers who say poorly trained guards attacked them while on Harrah&rsquo;s property. Each of the alleged attacks was captured on video by Harrah&rsquo;s in-house surveillance cameras.</p>
<p>A spokesman for the casino declined to comment</body>
```

where the body might have an address like : 120 morton street, philadelphia, PA

Comment: Kindly go to this:[http://www.aviyehuda.com/blog/2011/01/27/android-creating-links-using-linkfy/](http://www.aviyehuda.com/blog/2011/01/27/android-creating-links-using-linkfy/)

Comment: Thank you, but the link shows how to set the address but I need to find in the body of the text which one is an address. How to do that. The RSS feed which I am getting might have an address in the body of the text which is not highlighted. Android needs to find the address and highlight it.

Comment: you first need to define how you can know for sure that a chain of words/characters/numbers is an address.

Comment: Thats what I wanted to know. how to detect the chain of words that can be an address

Answer (score 0):

```
if (html.toString().contains(struniqID)) {
}
```

Comment: I am not going to search an unique address, it can be any address. Say in a webpage when you are visiting sometimes an address, phone # or email address highlighted, which might be clickable. Same way I need to figure out in the body of text which one is an address and highlight it

Comment: String struniqID="120 morton street, philadelphia, PA"

Comment: html string u find na? or that u want to do?

Comment: the string can be any address, I need to find out whether the string of chars in the body is the address